# Is it closed and compact?

Tags: general-topology

$A= f(B) \subseteq X$ where  $B =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 |1≤ x^2 +y^2 ≤ 2\}$. $X$  is an arbitrary topological space and $f :\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow X $ is an arbitrary continuous map.
which of the following  is correct.

1. open
2. closed
3. compact
4. connected

I know that  continuous image of a closed set is closed  as continuous image of compact is compact so  only  option 2 and option 3 is trues and correct.

Is it correct ? tell  me  where I'm wrong....I would be more thankful who give me hints or any solution.....thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not use the comment section for extended personal conversations.

Comment: For any space $A\ne \phi$ we can produce a space $X$ and a continuous $f:A\to X$ such that $f(B)$ is not closed in $X$ whenever $\phi\ne B\subset A,$  as follows: Let $T$ be the topology on $A.$ Let $X=A\cup \{p\}$ with $p \not \in A.$  Let the topology on $X$ be $T\cup \{X\}.$ Let $f=id_A.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is not Hausdorff, a compact set need not be closed. Also $B$ is connected, it is an annulus, so $f(B)$ is connected as well. You are indeed correct that the image is compact.

It is not necessarily open, for example, let $X=\mathbb R^2$, and have $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be the identity map.

Comment: To the proposer : The continuous image of a closed set is not necessarily closed. ....Examples: (1). $B=\{(x,1/x): x\in \Bbb R^+\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2.$  The projection  $p(x,y)=x$ is continuous from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R. $ But $p(B)=\Bbb R^+$ is not closed in $\Bbb R.$....(2). Let $B=A=\{0\} $ and $X=\{0,1\}$ where the topology on $X$ is $\{X,\phi\}.$  Any $f:A\to X$ is continuous, but  $f(B)=\{f(0)\}$ is not closed in $X.$

Comment: thanks Daniel wainfleet   and thanks  a  lot Andres mejia

Answer (score 1):

$B$ is compact $\implies$ $f(B)$ is compact $(\because$ continuous image of compact set is compact.)